# Table in subfile will not compile in main file

Tags: tables, longtable, subfiles

I have a table in a subfile I want to include in the main file (I use the subfiles packages).

The subfile compiles without problems, but when I try to compile the main file, I get this error:

```
Emergency stop.
<*> main.tex
            
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

Since I am new to LaTeX I used a generator to make the table, which I transformed into a longtable by myself. I apologize, if the code is really naïve! I have tried to search the web, but I can not find any solutions.

Here is my code for the subfile:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{figure}{0} 
\setcounter{table}{0} 
\landscape
  \centering
  \begin{longtable}[p]{@{}clrll@{}}
  \caption{Alle items vist fra eksperimentet. Bemærk, at relevante ord blot er farvet i denne tabel med rød/grøn for at markere afvigelsen. Alle ord blev vist med sort i selve eksperimentet. Til hvert item var også tilknyttet et billede, se nedenfor.}\\
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Item}}       & \textbf{Type}                                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Forekomst}} & \textbf{Afvigende}                                           & \textbf{Baseline}                                               \\ \midrule
  \multirow{3}{*}{1}                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Substantiv\\ (numerus)\end{tabular}} & 0                                      & Her er et bord.                                              & Her er et bord.                                                 \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 1                                      & På bordet ligger der to \textcolor{red}{blyante},            & På bordet ligger der to \textcolor{green}{blyanter}.            \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 0                                      & som har samme farve.                                         & som har forskellige farver.                                            \\ \midrule
  \multirow{3}{*}{2}                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Verbum\\ (participium)\end{tabular}} & 1                                      & Bo og Lis har \textcolor{red}{inviterede} gæster.            & Bo og Lis har \textcolor{green}{inviteret} gæster.              \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Til maden drikker de øl                                      & Til maden drikker de vin,                                       \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 0                                      & og bagefter spiller de spil.                                 & og bagefter spiller de spil.                                    \\ \midrule
  \multirow{3}{*}{3}                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Adjektiv\\ (numerus)\end{tabular}}   & 0                                      & Hanne har købt nyt hus.                                      & Hanne har købt nyt hus.                                         \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 1                                      & Hun er meget \textcolor{red}{lykkelige} for hendes nye hus.  & Hun er meget \textcolor{green}{lykkelig} for hendes nye hus.    \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Hun skal flytte ind til august.                              & Hun skal flytte ind til august.                                 \\ \midrule
  \multirow{3}{*}{4}                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Substantiv\\ (numerus)\end{tabular}} & 0                                      & Gitte leder efter et sted at parkere sin bil.                & Gitte leder efter et sted at parkere sin bil.                   \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Først er der ingen steder at parkere.                        & Først er der ingen steder at parkere.                           \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 1                                      & Men så er der to ledige \textcolor{red}{parkeringsplads}.    & Men så er der to ledige \textcolor{green}{parkeringspladser}.   \\ \midrule
  \multirow{3}{*}{5}                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Verbum\\ (præteritum)\end{tabular}}  & 0                                      & Anna elsker at rejse.                                        & Anna elsker at rejse.                                           \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 1                                      & Hun \textcolor{red}{besøgt} Malaysia i sommer,               & Hun \textcolor{green}{besøgte} Malaysia i sommer,               \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 0                                      & hun vil gerne rejse mere i Asien.                            & men hun vil aldrig rejse tilbage til Asien.                     \\ \midrule
  \multirow{3}{*}{6}                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Adjektiv\\ (genus)\end{tabular}}   & 1                                      & Mads er meget \textcolor{red}{gladt}.                        & Mads er meget \textcolor{green}{glad}.                          \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 0                                      & I dag er det nemlig hans fødselsdag,                         & I dag er det nemlig hans fødselsdag,                            \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 0                                      & og han får besøg af alle sine bedste fjender.                & han får besøg af alle sine bedstevenner.                        \\ \midrule
  \multirow{3}{*}{7}                      & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Verbum\\ (infinitiv)\end{tabular}}   & 0                                      & Lis og Dorthe savnede hinanden.                              & Lis og Dorthe savnede hinanden.                                 \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 1                                      & Så de havde mange ting at \textcolor{red}{taler} om,         & Så de havde mange ting at \textcolor{green}{tale} om,           \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 0                                      & og derfor sad de på caféen i mange timer.                    & og derfor skiltes de hurtigt.                                   \\ \midrule
  \multirow{4}{*}{8}                      & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Adjektiv\\ (grad)\end{tabular}}      & 0                                      & Hunden er ude at gå tur.                                     & Hunden er ude at gå tur.                                        \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 0                                      & I munden har den en bamse.                                   & I munden har den en bamse.                                      \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 1                                      & Bamsen er en \textcolor{red}{lillere} udgave af hunden,      & Bamsen er en \textcolor{green}{mindre} udgave af hunden,        \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 0                                      & og den er gul ligesom hunden.                                & og den er sort ligesom hunden.                                  \\ \midrule
  \multirow{5}{*}{9}                      & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Substantiv\\ (numerus)\end{tabular}} & 0                                      & Greta er blevet en ældre dame.                               & Greta er blevet en ældre dame.                                  \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 1                                      & Hun elsker at få \textcolor{red}{besøger} af sit barnebarn.  & Hun elsker at få \textcolor{green}{besøg} af sit barnebarn.     \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Når hun er på besøg,                                         & Når hun er på besøg,                                            \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 0                                      & serverer Greta te og småkager,                               & serverer Greta sodavand og is,                                  \\
                                          &                                                                                 & 0                                      & og så fortæller hun historier fra sin barndom.               & og så fortæller hun historier fra sin barndom.                  \\ \midrule
  \multirow{5}{*}{10}                     & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Adjektiv\\ (genus)\end{tabular}}     & 1                                      & Familien vil gerne male væggen \textcolor{red}{rødt}.        & Familien vil gerne male væggen \textcolor{green}{rød}.          \\
                                         &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Tidligere har væggen været malet hvid.                       & Tidligere har væggen været malet hvid.                          \\
                                         &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Men det, synes de, er for kedeligt,                          & Men det, synes de, er for kedeligt,                             \\
                                         &                                                                                 & 0                                      & og derfor er de trukket i arbejdstøjet.                      & og derfor er de trukket i arbejdstøjet.                         \\
                                         &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Men de orker ikke gå i gang.                                 & De glæder sig til at komme i gang.                              \\ \midrule
 \multirow{3}{*}{11}                     & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Substantiv\\ (numerus)\end{tabular}} & 1                                      & Maria og Svend er netop blevet \textcolor{red}{pensioniste}. & Maria og Svend er netop blevet \textcolor{green}{pensionister}. \\
                                         &                                                                                 & 2                                      & De har glædet sig til at blive \textcolor{red}{pensioniste}. & De har glædet sig til at blive \textcolor{green}{pensionister}. \\
                                         &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Nu har de tid til at gå tur i skoven.                        & Nu har de tid til at gå tur langs standen.                      \\ \midrule
 \multirow{3}{*}{12}                     & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Substantiv\\ (numerus)\end{tabular}} & 0                                      & Ida har ryddet op i sit legetøj.                             & Ida har ryddet op i sit legetøj.                                \\
                                         &                                                                                 & 1                                      & Nogle \textcolor{red}{tinge} blev smidt ud,                  & Nogle \textcolor{green}{ting} blev smidt ud,                    \\
                                         &                                                                                 & 2                                      & mens andre \textcolor{red}{tinge} blev givet til genbrug.    & mens andre \textcolor{green}{ting} blev givet til genbrug.      \\ \midrule
{\multirow{3}{*}{13}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Verbum\\ (participium)\end{tabular}} & 1                                      & Henrik har \textcolor{red}{pakkede} sin kuffert.             & Henrik har \textcolor{green}{pakket} sin kuffert.               \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 2                                      & Han har blandt andet \textcolor{red}{pakkede} sin snorkel.   & Han har blandt andet \textcolor{green}{pakket} sin snorkel.     \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Henrik skal nemlig på badeferie.                             & Henrik skal nemlig på skiferie.                                 \\ \midrule
{\multirow{3}{*}{14}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Substantiv\\ (grad)\end{tabular}}    & 1                                      & Æbletræet er det \textcolor{red}{gammelste} træ i haven.     & Æbletræet er det \textcolor{green}{ældste} træ i haven.         \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 2                                      & Tidligere var kirsebærtræet det \textcolor{red}{gammelste},  & Tidligere var kirsebærtræet det \textcolor{green}{ældste},      \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & men det blev fældet sidste år.                               & men det blev fældet sidste år.                                  \\ \midrule
{\multirow{4}{*}{15}} & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Substantiv\\ (numerus)\end{tabular}} & 1                                      & Frederik havde glemt sit \textcolor{red}{dankorte},          & Frederik havde glemt sit \textcolor{green}{dankort},            \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & da han handlede i Netto.                                     & da han handlede i Netto.                                        \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 2                                      & Heldigvis havde butikken hans \textcolor{red}{dankorte}.     & Heldigvis havde butikken hans \textcolor{green}{dankort}.       \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Frederik blev utrolig gal.                                   & Frederik blev utrolig glad.                                     \\ \midrule
{\multirow{4}{*}{16}} & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Verbum\\ (præsens)\end{tabular}}     & 0                                      & Liv er på vej i skole,                                       & Liv er på vej i skole,                                          \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 1                                      & da hun \textcolor{red}{møde} sin veninde på stationen.       & da hun \textcolor{green}{møder} sin veninde på stationen.       \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 2                                      & Liv \textcolor{red}{møde} tit sin veninde på stationen.      & Liv \textcolor{green}{møder} tit sin veninde på stationen.      \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & De går nemlig på den samme skole.                            & De går nemlig på den samme skole.                               \\ \midrule
{\multirow{4}{*}{17}} & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Adjektiv\\ (numerus)\end{tabular}}   & 1                                      & Oscar var \textcolor{red}{glade} for sin nye hundehvalp.     & Oscar var \textcolor{green}{glad} for sin nye hundehvalp.       \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Det skete dog tit,                                           & Det skete dog tit,                                              \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & at hvalpen tissede på gulvet.                                & at hvalpen tissede på gulvet.                                   \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 2                                      & Og da var Oscar knapt så \textcolor{red}{glade}.             & Og da var Oscar knapt så \textcolor{green}{glad}.               \\ \midrule
{\multirow{5}{*}{18}} & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Substantiv\\ (numerus)\end{tabular}} & 1                                      & Pigerne har samlet et par \textcolor{red}{stykke} fra vejen. & Pigerne har samlet et par \textcolor{green}{stykker} fra vejen. \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & De vil gerne lave et fodboldhold.                                      & De vil gerne lave et fodboldhold.                               \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & De er fire piger i alt.          & De er fire piger i alt.                                         \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 2                                      & Så de mangler et par \textcolor{red}{stykke} endnu.                                 & Så de mangler et par \textcolor{green}{stykker} endnu.           \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Man skal nemlig være elleve.                                  & Man skal nemlig være elleve.                                    \\ \midrule
{\multirow{5}{*}{19}} & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Verbum\\ (participium)\end{tabular}} & 0                                      & Luna er glad i dag.                                          & Luna er glad i dag.                                             \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 1                                      & For i dag har \textcolor{red}{være} en god dag.              & For i dag har \textcolor{green}{været} en god dag.              \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 2                                      & I dag har det \textcolor{red}{være} Lunas fødselsdag.        & I dag har det \textcolor{green}{været} Lunas fødselsdag.        \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Luna fik nogle gode gaver,                                   & Luna fik nogle gode gaver,                                      \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & og hun har haft en festhat på hele dagen.                    & og hun har haft en troldhat på hele dagen.                      \\ \midrule
{\multirow{5}{*}{20}} & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Adjektiv\\ (numerus)\end{tabular}} & 0                                      & Anja er på café.                                          & Anja er på café.                                             \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 1                                      & Hun bestiller en \textcolor{red}{sorte} kaffe.              & Hun bestiller en \textcolor{green}{sort} kaffe.              \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Tjeneren får byttet rundt på bestillingerne.        & Tjeneren får byttet rundt på bestillingerne.        \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 2                                      & Så Anja får ikke en \textcolor{red}{sorte} kaffe.                                   & Så Anja får ikke en \textcolor{green}{sort} kaffe.                                      \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & I stedet giver tjeneren hende en smoothie.                    & I stedet giver tjeneren hende en kakao.                      \\

 \\ \midrule
{\multirow{5}{*}{21}} & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Substantiv\\ (numerus)\end{tabular}} & 1                                      & Karin er vild med at afspille høj \textcolor{red}{musiker}.                                          & Karin er vild med at afspille høj \textcolor{green}{musik}.                                             \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 2                                      & Tit afspiller hun \textcolor{red}{musiker} fra 80'erne,              & Tit afspiller hun \textcolor{green}{musik} fra 80'erne,              \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & men også nogle gange noget moderne.        & men også nogle gange noget moderne.        \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 3                                      & Den høje \textcolor{red}{musiker} er til glæde for naboerne.                                   & Den høje \textcolor{green}{musik} er til glæde for naboerne.                                          \\

 \\ \midrule
{\multirow{5}{*}{22}} & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Substantiv\\ (numerus)\end{tabular}} & 1                                      & Mette har tit mange \textcolor{red}{aftale}.                                          & Mette har tit mange \textcolor{green}{aftaler}.                                             \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 2                                      & Tidligere glemte hun sine \textcolor{red}{aftale}.              & Tidligere glemte hun sine \textcolor{green}{aftaler}.              \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Men hun er blevet bedre,        & Men hun er blevet bedre,        \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 3                                      & efter hun skriver sine \textcolor{red}{aftale} i kalenderen.                                   & efter hun skriver sine \textcolor{green}{aftaler} i kalenderen.                                      \\

 \\ \midrule
{\multirow{5}{*}{23}} & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Verbum\\ (præsens)\end{tabular}} & 0                                      & Det er jul,                                          & Det er jul,                                             \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 1                                      & og børnene \textcolor{red}{flettes} julehjerter.              & og børnene \textcolor{green}{fletter} julehjerter.              \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 2                                      & Mie \textcolor{red}{flettes} et hjerte i rødt og hvidt.        & Mie \textcolor{green}{fletter} et hjerte i rødt og hvidt.        \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 3                                      & Men Kalle \textcolor{red}{flettes} et hjerte i gult og blåt.                                   & Men Kalle \textcolor{green}{fletter} et hjerte i gult og blåt.                                      \\

{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Kalle er nemlig Brøndbyfan.                                   & Kalle er nemlig Brøndbyfan.                                      \\

 \\ \midrule
{\multirow{5}{*}{24}} & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Verbum\\ (infinitiv)\end{tabular}} & 1                                      & Landmanden er ude at \textcolor{red}{kørte} i sin traktor.                                          & Landmanden er ude at \textcolor{green}{køre} i sin traktor.                                             \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 2                                      & Han elsker at \textcolor{red}{kørte} i sin traktor.              & Han elsker at \textcolor{green}{køre} i sin traktor.              \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Undtagen når der skal spredes gylle.        & Undtagen når der skal spredes gylle.        \\
{}                    &                                                                                 & 3                                      & Så elsker han knapt så meget at \textcolor{red}{kørte}.                                   & Så elsker han knapt så meget at \textcolor{green}{køre}.                                      \\

{}                    &                                                                                 & 0                                      & Kalle er nemlig Brøndbyfan.                                   & Kalle er nemlig Brøndbyfan.                                      \\
\midrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it truly the table that is causing the problem?  If you replace it with a single letter, do you still have the problem?  If not, what part of the table is causing the problem?  Could you provide the MWE of your main file that includes this subfile?